# Как запретить NaN?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Код `AppHelpers.formatNumber(total)`, иногда возвращает `NaN` и вставляет его в страницу. Пытался через `if, isNaN`, результата нет. Вообщем нужно чтобы вместо `NaN` был `0`

Comment: `AppHelpers.formatNumber()` возвращает строку `"NaN"` или число `NaN`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Возможно прозвучит дико, однако есть такой способ проверить число на NaN

```
var y = 0/0; // тут явный NaN
if (y === y){ // потому как NaN === NaN => false
  //значит y это число
} else{
  // иначе это NaN или undefined
  return 0; // или любой другой ответ
}
```

Comment: может я конечно жестко туплю но, как значение === значение будет `false`? У меня ещё не получилось провернуть с вашим примером подобное, чтобы было `false`. А то что тип `NaN === NaN = false` это да

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Ну в моем примере 100% пройдет по блоку else. Я просто изобразил как можно сделать (var y=2; чисто для определения что такое y). Поэтому вы абсолютно правы =>  y ===y всегда true для конечного определенного значения.

Comment: У меня не проходит)) Если например убрать return (т.к. мы не в методе) а добавить вывод в консоль, то выведет что это число)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Ну я не знаю как вам помочь, т.к. мой пример делает ровно то, что он должен и является валидным (запускается)

Comment: работать то работает) но не false) а true

Answer (score 5):

Есть специальная функция для этого, `isNaN(<variable>)`, возвращает `true` если переменная равна `NaN`:

```
var result = AppHelpers.formatNumber(total);
if (isNaN(result)) result = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Самый простой вариант:

```
x = AppHelpers.formatNumber(total) || 0
```

Его недостаток в том, что он будет подменять нулём не только NaN, но и другие значения, которые соответствуют false (например, пустая строка).

Но если на выходе вы только числа и ожидаете, то этот код будет вполне хорошо работать.

Answer (score 2):

Верного решения так и нашел. Пришлось писать костыль самому:

```
        let totalSum = AppHelpers.formatNumber(total) + ''; // Преобразование в строку
        if (totalSum == 'NaN') return 0;
```

Comment: Странное заявление, учитывая наличие 2ух ответов выше. Но все ответы верные в той или иной мере.